# Problem with pywhatkit error module not found

Tags: python, module, whatsapp

I have an issue with pywhatkit:

code:
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+39123456789", "Hi", 6, 13)

Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\angelo\Desktop\whatsapp.py", line 1, in 
import pywhatkit
File "C:\Users\angelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit_*init*_.py", line 29, in 
from pywhatkit.remotekit import start_server
File "C:\Users\angelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\remotekit.py", line 6, in 
from flask import Flask, request
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (unknown location)

Installation 1:

pip install pywhatkit.py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywhatkit.py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywhatkit.py

Installation 2:

py -m pip install pywhatkit
Requirement already satisfied: pywhatkit in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pywhatkit) (2.28.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wikipedia in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pywhatkit) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pywhatkit) (0.9.53)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pywhatkit) (9.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pymsgbox in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: PyTweening>=1.0.1 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyscreeze>=0.1.21 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.1.28)
Requirement already satisfied: pygetwindow>=0.0.5 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: mouseinfo in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (2022.6.15)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from wikipedia->pywhatkit) (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrect in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pygetwindow>=0.0.5->pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->wikipedia->pywhatkit) (2.3.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from mouseinfo->pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.8.2)

Path:
C:\Users\angelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\angelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%USERPROFILE%.dotnet\tools;c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages;c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages;

C:\Users\angelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

%USERPROFILE%.dotnet\tools

c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages\

c:\users\angelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help
Angelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this line:

python -m install flask

Now it works.

Angelo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).